# Rails 2.3.8 Compound condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I have a rails query that I would like to run. The only problem that I am having is the query structure.

Essentially the query looks like this

```
queryList = model.find(:all, :conditions => [id = "id"])
#returns a query list

#here is the issue
compound = otherModel.find(:first, :select => "an_id", 
                                   :conditions => ["some_other_id=? and an_id=?, some_other_id, an_id])
```

Where an_id is actually a list of ids in the query list. How can I write that in rails to basically associate a single id to a list that may contain ids...

Answer (score 1):

If you use a hash as conditions, the operation is an AND.

```
obj = Model.first(:conditions => {:field1 => "val1", :field2 => "val2"})
```

Comment: What if val2 is an array. That is what I have as my current issue.

Comment: @MichaelGuantonio: Wouldn't `:an_id => some_array` get turned into the SQL `an_id in (id1, id2, ...)`? That's what Rails3+ would do at least.

Comment: The issue here is that :an_id is a search term for the list and an_id exsists as a different id name for the object. So its :an_id (of model otherModel) needs to look into the array and associate :foo_id to an_id an then do an in search.